# Is there a public source for US senate amendments?

Tags: united-states, senate

I've recently come into a discussion about a part of the [Inflation Reduction act](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/5376/text) that was struck by the Senate after Mr. Graham's Point of Order.

When I discuss about laws, I always like to have the receipts, i.e. the full text.
This way we don't have to reason about second hand sources like the senators talking about it.

For this situation, this seems incredibly difficult:
While the bill is public [here](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/5376/text), and [this](https://www.congress.gov/amendment/117th-congress/senate-amendment/5194/actions) shows all the actions that have been done to this Amendment (including striking page 744, line 7, through page 755, line 4, as per Graham's point of Order), there seems to be no public place where we can see the version of the Amendment these page numbers relate to.

[The congressional record](https://www.congress.gov/amendment/117th-congress/senate-amendment/5194/text) clearly uses a different layout which will make the line numbers not useful, [This senate version](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/5376/text/eas) only has 730 pages, and [that senate version](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/5376/text/pcs) is from March - clearly not the same thing.

Is there a good place to get the Amendment (S.Amdt.5194) in its original form to see what the section Mr. Graham struck really would have done?

I did take a look at [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/47958/44264), but this doesn't seem to apply in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language that was stricken from the amendment appears to have been the text in [Title IX](https://www.congress.gov/117/crec/2022/08/06/168/133/CREC-2022-08-06-pt1-PgS4070-2.pdf#page=74) of S.Amdt.5194. This title does not appear in [the final enrolled bill](https://congress.gov/117/bills/hr5376/BILLS-117hr5376enr.pdf), H.R.5376.

Title IX of S.Amdt.5194 would have capped the [price of insulin for private insurance](https://www.salon.com/2022/08/07/block-insulin-price-cap-for-private-insurance-in-inflation-reduction-act/).

---

There is no fixed procedure for locating the information. In this case, the key elements were:

- S.Amdt.5194 was introduced as a substitute, replacing all significant parts of H.R.5376
- The point of order was related to text about the cost of insulin
- There were two parts of the amendment that made references to insulin
- The second part (Title IX) didn't appear in the final enrolled bill

It is likely that, between the Saturday and Sunday sessions, the Senate created an *internal* document containing the text with line numbers the Graham used.

Comment: Are these 'internal documents' eventually put on the public record? if not, how would anyone know what the law is referring to?

Comment: @M.Y.Zuo - Bills, resolutions and reports are printed and made public by the GPO; amendments are made public by publishing them in the Congressional Record (CR). Any inactive, *internal* documents go the the National Archives at the end of each two-year session. It is not clear to me whether such archived records are available to the public. To understand a bill or resolution, I look at the summary provided by the CRS. To understand an amendment, I read the comments in the CR by the sponsor.